# Without change, images can suddenly not be found. Why?

Tags: includegraphics

I include some images in my latex document with a code like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{graphs/"my graphs"/"graph 1".png}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{graphs/"my graphs"/"graph 2".png}
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
```

Without any change (not any I know of anyway), TeXstudio was unable to find these graphs although there were no problems before.
The error message is:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `graphs/"my graphs"/"graph 1".png' not found: using draft setting. ...hs/"my graphs"/"graph 1".png}
```

Now, when I change the file name (and the reference in the document) from `graph 1` to `graph_1`, it works perfectly. Even when I change the name back to `graph 1`, it works just fine!

I workaround would be, of cause, the rename every file and reference; and change it back again.
But as I included many graphs, this would be tedious.
Also, I want to know why this happened!

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I do understand that using spaces is not recommended, but as it worked before, this is not really my point.
I added an image that describes my process:

[image]

Comment: it will save you lots of time if you simply avoid to use spaces in file names.

Comment: latex has no state, if you edit the file and then edit it back then it is equivalent to not editing it, so your description can not be right.

Comment: Seems like `"graphs/my graphs/graph 1.png"` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Werner (currently) you need the `.png` outside the quotes or latex will see the extension as `.png"`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: :-o

Comment: Hey everyone, please have a look at my edit!

Comment: Just guessing, but are you sure that the “space” character in your file (I mean, the *original* one, not the one you type to replace `_`) is a genuine ASCII code 32?